# Изограмма в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Нужно написать функцию,которая определяет, изограмма ли данный текст (слово) или нет, то есть в нем повторяются буквы или нет.

Например: слово Андрей - изограм, слово Анастасия - нет.

Comment: [Может наоборот](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogram): "Андрей" - является, а "Анастасия" - нет?

Comment: о,да,ошибся,спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
function isIsogram(str) {
  const normalized = str.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase();
  return normalized.length === new Set(normalized).size;
}

console.log(isIsogram('Андрей'));
console.log(isIsogram('Анастасия'));
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
const isIsogram = (str) => !!str.toLowerCase().split``.filter((h => v => (h[v] = (h[v] || 0) + 1) === 2)({})).length;


console.log(isIsogram('Анастасия'));
console.log(isIsogram('Андрей'));
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogram

Comment: @martiliones, я искренне рад, что вы гораздо сильней меня в области лингвистики, но я ориентировался на желаемый результат, описанный в вопросе, а именно на пример результата. Отдельное спасибо за минус, который никак не связан с JS и подтолкнет меня впредь уделять больше внимания терминалогии. ))

Comment: Извините, что кто-то влепил вам минус. На несоответствие формулировки обратил внимание я, но я не думал, что кто-то будет из-за этого ставить минусы - ведь хотя ответы после правки "обесценились", но это настолько минорно... Добавил плюс в целях восстановления справедливости.

Answer (score 2):

Данное решение предполагает только один проход по буквам слова, соответственно работает за линейное время `O(n)`

```js
const isIsogram = (str) => {
  const check = {};
  for (const l of str) {
    if (check[l]) return true;
    check[l] = true;
  }
  return false;
}


console.log(isIsogram('Анастасия'));
console.log(isIsogram('Андрей'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Неочевидно, должны ли считаться разными символы, отличающиеся регистром. Если да, то можно так:

```js
const isIsogram = str => new Set(str).size === str.length;

console.log(isIsogram('Анастасия'));
console.log(isIsogram('Андрей'));
```

Если нет, то можно написать `new Set(str.toLowerCase())`.